# Горячие клавиши, чтобы вернуться после того, как перешел к источнику метода\класса?

Tags: android-studio, hotkeys

Вопрос по hotkeys Android Studio.
Когда я нажимаю <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>LeftMouse button</kbd> или <kbd>F4</kbd> - я перехожу к источнику  (метода, класса....). Как вернуться назад к тому месту, где был до перехода?

Comment: Сейчас я нажимаю SHIFT+F4, открывается новое окно и там перехожу, а когда закончил смотреть - закрываю его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По <kbd>F4</kbd> источник (другой класс) открывается в соседней вкладке, поэтому просто нажмите на крестик в заголовке вкладки или <kbd>CTRL +F4</kbd> (Close), если нужна именно горячая клавиша и перейдете к предыдущей вкладке - в данном случае к той, в которой нажимали <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Если закрывать открытую по <kbd>F4</kbd> вкладку не надо или навигация осуществляется внутри одного класса (переход к методу), то нажмите <kbd>CTRL + ALT + LEFT</kbd> (Back) - вернуться к предыдущей позиции курсора, если переход был внутри класса или к предыдущей вкладке, если была открыта новая ну и <kbd>CTRL + ALT + RIGHT</kbd> (Forward) - опять к той, откуда пришли. Действие этих клавиш - шаг назад (вперед) в навигации.

Если горячие клавиши отличаются от дефолтных или система не Windows, то посмотреть комбинацию можно, проследовав: *Navigate -> Back* (справа будет комбинация клавиш)

[image: scrn]

Ну и все назначенные комбинации можно посмотреть, проследовав: *File -> Settings -> Keymap*

Comment: Не то, я говорю о навигации в одном классе.

Comment: В одном классе так же действует CTRL + ALT + LEFT для возврата на то место в классе, откуда была нажата F4

Comment: Сейчас попробую что-то, у меня эта комбинация переворачивае экран ноута на 90градусов)))

Comment: @Igor Скорее всего такая же комбинация используется в горячих клавишах самого ноута - тогда одну из комбинаций нужно переназначить